# Numeric Navigation Blogger Label and Search Not Showing

Tags: javascript, html, css, widget, blogger

I've added numeric navigation, it works fine on the home page, but doesn't work on search / label, and web search.

- this is my blog :
  https://codeselecteds.blogspot.com/
- This results from the search label and numeric navigation not working :
  https://codeselecteds.blogspot.com/search/label/Python
- these are web search results :
  https://codeselecteds.blogspot.com/search?q=cara

This is the code includable in the nextprev post :

```
<b:includable id='nextprev'>
  <div class='blog-pager' id='blog-pager'/>
</b:includable>
```

This is code js nextprev :

```
<script type='text/javascript'> /*<![CDATA[*/ 

var postperpage=1; 
var numshowpage=2; 
var upPageWord ='Next'; 
var downPageWord ='Prev'; 
var urlactivepage=location.href; 
var home_page="/"; 

/*]]>*/ </script>
      
<script type='text/javascript'> /*<![CDATA[*/ 

var nopage;
var jenis;
var nomerhal;
var lblname1;
halamanblogger();

function loophalaman(banyakdata)
{
  var html='';
  nomerkiri=parseInt(numshowpage/2);

  if(nomerkiri==numshowpage-nomerkiri)
  {
    numshowpage=nomerkiri*2+1
  }
  mulai=nomerhal-nomerkiri;

  if(mulai<1)mulai=1;maksimal=parseInt(banyakdata/postperpage)+1;

  if(maksimal-1==banyakdata/postperpage)
    maksimal=maksimal-1;
    akhir=mulai+numshowpage-1;

  if(akhir>maksimal)
    akhir=maksimal;
    html+="<span class='showpageOf'><a>"+nomerhal+'/'+maksimal+"</a></span>";
    var prevnomer=parseInt(nomerhal)-1;

    if(nomerhal>1)
    {
      if(nomerhal==2)
      {
        if(jenis=="page")
        {
          html+='<span class="showpage"><a href="'+home_page+'">'+upPageWord+'</a></span>'
        }
      }
      else
      {
        if(jenis=="page")
        {
          html+='<span class="showpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage('+prevnomer+');return false">'+upPageWord+'</a></span>'
        }
        else
        {
          html+='<span class="showpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel('+prevnomer+');return false">'+upPageWord+'</a></span>'
        }
      }
    }
    if(mulai>1){if(jenis=="page")
    {
      html+='<span class="showpageNum"><a href="'+home_page+'">1</a></span>'
    }
  }

  if(mulai>2)
  {
    html+='<span class="showpage"> ... </span>'
  }

  for(var jj=mulai;jj<=akhir;jj++)
  {
    if(nomerhal==jj)
    {
      html+='<span class="showpagePoint"><a>'+jj+'</a></span>'
    }
    else if(jj==1)
    {
      if(jenis=="page")
      {
        html+='<span class="showpageNum"><a href="'+home_page+'">1</a></span>'
      }
    }
    else
    {
      if(jenis=="page")
      {
        html+='<span class="showpageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage('+jj+');return false">'+jj+'</a></span>'
      }
      else
      {
        html+='<span class="showpageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel('+jj+');return false">'+jj+'</a></span>'
      }
    }
  }

  if(akhir<maksimal-1)
  {
    html+='<span class="showpage"> ... </span>'
  }

  if(akhir<maksimal)
  {
    if(jenis=="page")
    {
      html+='<span class="showpageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage('+maksimal+');return false">'+maksimal+'</a></span>'
    }
    else
    {
      html+='<span class="showpageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel('+maksimal+');return false">'+maksimal+'</a></span>'
    }
  }

  var nextnomer=parseInt(nomerhal)+1;

  if(nomerhal<maksimal)
  {
    if(jenis=="page")
    {
      html+='<span class="showpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage('+nextnomer+');return false">'+downPageWord+'</a></span>'
    }
    else
    {
      html+='<span class="showpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectlabel('+nextnomer+');return false">'+downPageWord+'</a></span>'
    }
  }

  var pageArea=document.getElementsByName("pageArea");
  var blogPager=document.getElementById("blog-pager");

  for(var p=0;p<pageArea.length;p++)
  {
    pageArea[p].innerHTML=html
  }

  if(pageArea&&pageArea.length>0)
  {
    html=''
  }

  if(blogPager)
  {
    blogPager.innerHTML=html
  }
}

function hitungtotaldata(root)
{
  var feed=root.feed;
  var totaldata=parseInt(feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,10);
  loophalaman(totaldata)
}

function halamanblogger()
{
  var thisUrl=urlactivepage;
  

  if(thisUrl.indexOf(".html") == -1)
  {
    if(thisUrl.indexOf("/search/label/")==-1)
    {
      jenis="page";
      if(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=")!=-1)
      {
        nomerhal=urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=")+8,urlactivepage.length)
      }
      else
      {
        nomerhal=1
      }
      if(thisUrl.indexOf("q=") == -1){
        document.write("<script src=\""+home_page+"feeds/posts/summary?max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=hitungtotaldata\"><\/script>")
      }
      else 
      {
        document.write("<script src=\"" + home_page + "feeds/posts/summary?q=" + thisUrl.split("?")[1].split("q=")[1].split("&")[0] + "&alt=json-in-script&callback=totalcountdata\"><\/script>")
      }
    }
    else
    {
      jenis="label";
      if(thisUrl.indexOf("&max-results=")==-1)
      {
        postperpage=20
      }
      if(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=")!=-1)
      {
        nomerhal=urlactivepage.substring(urlactivepage.indexOf("#PageNo=")+8,urlactivepage.length)
      }
      else
      {
        nomerhal=1
      }
    }
  }
}

function redirectpage(numberpage)
{
  jsonstart=(numberpage-1)*postperpage;nopage=numberpage;
  var nBody=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var newInclude=document.createElement('script');
  newInclude.type='text/javascript';
  newInclude.setAttribute("src",home_page+"feeds/posts/summary?start-index="+jsonstart+"&max-results=1&alt=json-in-script&callback=finddatepost");
  nBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}

function redirectlabel(numberpage)
{
  jsonstart=(numberpage-1)*postperpage;nopage=numberpage;
  var nBody=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var newInclude=document.createElement('script');
  newInclude.type='text/javascript'; 
  nBody.appendChild(newInclude)
}

function finddatepost(root)
{
  post=root.feed.entry[0];
  var timestamp1=post.published.$t.substring(0,19)+post.published.$t.substring(23,29);
  var timestamp=encodeURIComponent(timestamp1);
  if(jenis=="page")
  { 
    if(urlactivepage.indexOf("?q=") == -1){
      var alamat="/search?updated-max="+timestamp+"&max-results="+postperpage+"#PageNo="+nopage
    }else {
            var pAddress = "/search?updated-max=" + timestamp + "&q="+ urlactivepage.split("?")[1].split("q=")[1].split("&")[0] +"&max-results=" + perPage + "#PageNo=" + noPage
        }
  }
  location.href=alamat
} 
/*]]>*/ </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can by using this :

```
<div class="nav-nextrep" id="nav-nextrep">
    <div style="display: none;">
        <span class="showpageOf"><a>1/6</a></span>
    </div>
    <span class="showpagePoint"><a>1</a></span>
    <span class="showpageNum">
        <a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(2);return false">2</a>
    </span>
    <span class="showpageNum">
        <a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(3);return false">3</a>
    </span>
    <span class="showpage">-</span>
    <span class="showpageNum"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(6);return false">6</a></span>
    <span class="showpage"><a href="#" onclick="redirectpage(2);return false">&gt;</a></span>
</div>
```